# Showing that a completely regular semigroup $S$ is orthodox if and only if $\left(\forall x,y \in S\right) \space xy=xyy^{-1}x^{-1}xy$.

Tags: group-theory, semigroups

From J. M. Howie's *Fundamentals of Semigroup Theory*, Exercise 9, page 139: A semigroup $S$ is called [*orthodox*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthodox_semigroup) if it is regular and the idempotents form a subsemigroup. How would I show that a [completely regular semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_regular_semigroup) $S$ is orthodox if and only if $\left(\forall x,y \in S\right) \space xy=xyy^{-1}x^{-1}xy$?

**Things I know:**

- A semigroup $S$ is completely simple and orthodox $\iff$ it is a rectangular group (that is, $S \cong G \times B$, where $G$ is a group and $B$ is a rectangular band.
- $S$ is a rectangular group $\iff$ it is completely regular and satisfies $x^{-1}yy^{-1}x=x^{-1}x.$
- A *[Clifford semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_semigroup)* is defined as a completely regular semigroup $\left(S, \mu, \space^{-1}\right)$ in which, $\forall\space x,y \in S,$
  $$\left(xx^{-1}\right)\left(yy^{-1}\right)=\left(yy^{-1}\right)\left(xx^{-1}\right).$$

Any help you can give would be much appreciated.

Comment: What means $\mu$ in your definition of a Clifford semigroup?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin $\mu$ is a binary operation, $\mu: \left(a,b\right)\mapsto ab$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**. (1) First prove that if $e$ is idempotent, then $e^{-1} = e$.

(2) Suppose that $S$ is completely regular and satisfies the identity 
$$
(*) \qquad xy=xyy^{-1}x^{-1}xy.
$$To prove that the idempotents form a semigroup, apply $(*)$ with $x$ and $y$ idempotent.

(3) Suppose now that $S$ is orthodox. To prove $(*)$, observe that $xyy^{-1}x^{-1}xy = (xx^{-1}x)yy^{-1}x^{-1}x(yy^{-1}y) = x(x^{-1}xyy^{-1})^2y$

Comment: For (1); Let $e$ be an idempotent element of $S$. Then, since $S$ is completely regular $\exists$ a unary operation on $S$ with the following properties: (**1**) $(e^{-1})^{-1}=e$, (**2**) $ee^{-1}e=e$, (**3**) $ee^{-1}=e^{-1}e$. Then, $e=ee^{-1}e=e^{-1}ee=e^{-1}e=e^{-1}ee^{-1}e=(e^{-1}e)(ee^{-1})=e^{-1}ee^{-1}=e^{-1}$.

Comment: For (2), suppose that $S$ is completely regular and $xy=xyy^{-1}x^{-1}xy \space \forall x,y \in S$. Now, let $e,f \in S$ be idempotent elements, then: $ef=eff^{-1}e^{-1}ef=effeef=efef=(ef)^{2}$ and $\therefore$ $ef$ is idempotent (since $e$ and $f$ are idempotents and $e=e^{-1}, f=f^{-1}$).  Thus, idempotents of $S$ form a subsemigroup and hence $S$ is orthodox?

Comment: Excellent. Did you complete (3)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't been able to make much progress with (3). I've been able to show that $xy=x(x^{-1}xyy^{-1})y$ which then leads me to try and show that $x^{-1}xyy^{-1}$ is idempotent?

Comment: But you know that $x^{-1}x$ is idempotent, right?

Comment: I think by property **(2)** of a completely regular semigroup we have that $x^{-1}x=x^{-1}xx^{-1}x=(x^{-1}x)^{2}$ and similarly $yy^{-1}=yy^{-1}yy^{-1}=(yy^{-1})^{2}$. However, I still can't show that $(x^{-1}xyy^{-1})^{2}=(x^{-1}xyy^{-1})$.

Comment: For (3), we assume that $S$ is orthodox...

Comment: So composition/multiplication of idempotents is idempotent; $\therefore$ since $x^{-1}x$ is idempotent and $yy^{-1}$ is idempotent then $x^{-1}xyy^{-1}$ is idempotent and we're done by using hint (3)?

Comment: Yes, you're done...